# How can I perform sound classification based on spectrograms and waveforms?

Tags: audio, spectrogram

I noticed that almost all machine learning enabled sound classification approaches use spectrograms or MFCCs as input for feature extraction.
I am new to the area and would like to know if we can also combine waveforms and spectrograms/MFCCs of sounds to classify them more accurately.
Then, is there a deep learning approach that does not require any pre-processing and relies simply on raw audio data?

Comment: You can basically put whatever you want into a classifier, and it'll help accuracy if there's more information about what you want to classify in it than what it contributes in confusion. MFCCs just model sound-generating processes relatively well, and it seems a wise choice to use them. Technically, if you use the raw sound, you might as well omit the MFCCs alltogether – they only contain info also contained in the original sound – but it might never finish training with a finite set of training data. MFCCs are a good starting point;unless you've got a good reason not to rely on them,use 'em.

Comment: Thanks, Marcus. Could you provide me with an example that uses the raw data, the waveform or the combination of wavefom+MFCC as an input? Cheers!

Comment: no, and how would that even help you? You could just take any other example (using MFCCs or anything else) and train that with a different kind of input. Neural networks don't care. It's just that it's easier to learn something from well-prepared data than from raw data.

Comment: Yep - wavenets (or sincnets) work straight on audio samples.